# ChartJS Linegraph not drawing lines

Tags: javascript, php, json, chart.js

I am attempting to create a linegraph using chartjs, but the lines do not show. I am not sure why they do not show. I have tried googling this issue with no results, and would appreciate any help. Below is Chart JS code, and the JSON code. This wants me to add more details but I'm not sure what else to say.

Chart Code:

```
               url: "past30daysubs.php",
               method: "GET",

               success: function (data) {
                   console.log(data);
                   var subholding = [];
                   var Emails = [];
                   var Websites = [];

                   for (var i in data['websites']) {
                       console.log('ret:' + i);
                       console.log('ret:' + data['websites'][i]);
                       
                       subholding.push("" + dateFns.format(Date(i),'MM/DD/YYYY'));
                       //Emails.push(data[i].emails);
                       Websites.push(data['websites'][i]);
                   //console.log("" + dateFns.format(Date(data[i].seen),'MM/DD/YYYY'));
                   }
                  for (var i in data['emailss']) {
                       console.log('ret:' + i);
                       console.log('ret:' + data['emails'][i]);
                       
                       subholding.push("" + dateFns.format(Date(i),'MM/DD/YYYY'));
                       //Emails.push(data[i].emails);
                       Emails.push(data['emails'][i]);
                   //console.log("" + dateFns.format(Date(data[i].seen),'MM/DD/YYYY'));
                   }

                   console.log(Websites)
         
                   var ctx = document.getElementById("mycanvas").getContext("2d");
                   var barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  labels: ['Websites','Emails'],
  data: {
    label: subholding, //data.map(o => subholding ),
    datasets: [{
      label: "Emails",
      borderColor: "rgba(59, 89, 152, 1)",
      data: Emails
    },
   {   
     label: "Websites",
     borderColor: "rgba(59, 89, 152, 1)",
     data: Websites
    },
    ],
  },
  options: {
              responsive: true,

    scales: {
      x: {
        type: 'time',
        time: {
        format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
        unit: 'day',
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
               },
               error: function (data) {
                   console.log(data);
               }
           });
});
```

and example JSON Data:

```
{"websites":{"2023-06-27 16:12:50":22146,"2023-06-27 16:13:50":1,"2023-06-27 16:28:25":16,"2023-06-27 16:29:19":8,"2023-06-27 16:29:20":27,"2023-06-27 16:30:17":35,"2023-06-27 16:31:05":16,"2023-06-27 16:31:06":2,"2023-06-27 16:32:18":4,"2023-06-27 16:32:45":8,"2023-06-27 16:34:25":11,"2023-06-27 16:35:34":18,"2023-06-27 16:35:40":10,"2023-06-27 16:36:59":6,"2023-06-27 16:37:08":6,"2023-06-27 16:38:29":1,"2023-06-27 16:38:32":1,"2023-06-27 16:39:59":4,"2023-06-27 16:40:03":20,"2023-06-27 16:41:33":3,"2023-06-27 16:41:36":1,"2023-06-27 16:43:01":1,"2023-06-27 16:44:25":3,"2023-06-27 16:45:29":15,"2023-06-27 16:49:58":44,"2023-06-27 16:50:02":11,"2023-06-27 16:50:06":20,"2023-06-27 16:50:07":24,"2023-06-27 16:50:08":48,"2023-06-27 16:50:09":45,"2023-06-27 16:50:10":31,"2023-06-27 16:50:11":23,"2023-06-27 16:50:12":6,"2023-06-27 16:50:13":25,"2023-06-27 16:50:14":10,"2023-06-27 16:50:16":21,"2023-06-27 16:50:17":5,"2023-06-27 16:50:20":3,"2023-06-27 16:51:25":12,"2023-06-27 16:51:26":25,"2023-06-27 16:51:32":4,"2023-06-27 16:51:45":13,"2023-06-27 16:51:54":5,"2023-06-27 16:52:00":13,"2023-06-27 16:52:01":46,"2023-06-27 16:52:02":17,"2023-06-27 16:52:03":30,"2023-06-27 16:52:04":30,"2023-06-27 16:52:05":12,"2023-06-27 16:52:06":8,"2023-06-27 16:52:07":28,"2023-06-27 16:52:08":6,"2023-06-27 16:52:09":18,"2023-06-27 16:52:10":3,"2023-06-27 16:52:11":11,"2023-06-27 16:52:48":2,"2023-06-27 16:53:04":21,"2023-06-27 16:53:10":2,"2023-06-27 16:53:16":10,"2023-06-27 16:53:20":19,"2023-06-27 16:53:21":14,"2023-06-27 16:53:22":14,"2023-06-27 16:53:23":29,"2023-06-27 16:53:24":3,"2023-06-27 16:53:25":13,"2023-06-27 16:53:26":28,"2023-06-27 16:53:27":12,"2023-06-27 16:53:28":6,"2023-06-27 16:53:29":8,"2023-06-27 16:53:30":4,"2023-06-27 16:53:36":4,"2023-06-27 16:54:10":11,"2023-06-27 16:54:13":5,"2023-06-27 16:54:23":5,"2023-06-27 16:54:29":4,"2023-06-27 16:54:35":4,"2023-06-27 16:54:38":13,"2023-06-27 16:54:39":23,"2023-06-27 16:54:40":8,"2023-06-27 16:54:41":12,"2023-06-27 16:54:42":13,"2023-06-27 16:54:43":40,"2023-06-27 16:54:44":9,"2023-06-27 16:54:45":7,"2023-06-27 16:54:54":4,"2023-06-27 16:55:04":1,"2023-06-27 16:55:13":1,"2023-06-27 16:55:32":6,"2023-06-27 16:55:38":1,"2023-06-27 16:55:57":1,"2023-06-27 16:56:06":1,"2023-06-27 16:56:16":1,"2023-06-27 16:56:22":1,"2023-06-27 16:56:31":2,"2023-06-27 16:56:32":3,"2023-06-27 16:56:33":11,"2023-06-27 16:56:34":11,"2023-06-27 16:56:35":16,"2023-06-27 16:56:36":2,"2023-06-27 16:56:45":1,"2023-06-27 16:57:00":1,"2023-06-27 16:57:03":1,"2023-06-27 16:57:26":1,"2023-06-27 16:57:35":1,"2023-06-27 16:58:19":1,"2023-06-27 16:58:20":1,"2023-06-27 16:58:58":1,"2023-06-27 16:59:26":1,"2023-06-27 16:59:47":1,"2023-06-27 16:59:57":2,"2023-06-27 17:00:13":2,"2023-06-27 17:00:18":1,"2023-06-27 17:00:49":1,"2023-06-27 17:01:29":4,"2023-06-27 17:01:33":3,"2023-06-27 17:01:34":7,"2023-06-27 17:01:35":3,"2023-06-27 17:01:36":6,"2023-06-27 17:01:37":6,"2023-06-27 17:01:38":15,"2023-06-27 17:01:39":5,"2023-06-27 17:02:17":1,"2023-06-27 17:02:39":4,"2023-06-27 17:02:48":6,"2023-06-27 17:02:49":7,"2023-06-27 17:02:50":7,"2023-06-27 17:02:51":6,"2023-06-27 17:02:52":16,"2023-06-27 17:02:53":6,"2023-06-27 17:02:54":5,"2023-06-27 17:02:55":4,"2023-06-27 17:02:56":13,"2023-06-27 17:02:57":7,"2023-06-27 17:02:58":5,"2023-06-27 17:02:59":7,"2023-06-27 17:03:00":8,"2023-06-27 17:03:01":5,"2023-06-27 17:03:02":4,"2023-06-27 17:03:03":2,"2023-06-27 17:03:07":1,"2023-06-27 17:03:16":2,"2023-06-27 17:03:35":1,"2023-06-27 17:03:38":1,"2023-06-27 17:03:39":5,"2023-06-27 17:03:40":9,"2023-06-27 17:03:41":1,"2023-06-27 17:03:42":9,"2023-06-27 17:03:43":1,"2023-06-27 17:03:44":6,"2023-06-27 17:03:45":4,"2023-06-27 17:03:46":5,"2023-06-27 17:03:47":6,"2023-06-27 17:04:03":7,"2023-06-27 17:04:04":1,"2023-06-27 17:04:16":5,"2023-06-27 17:04:23":1,"2023-06-27 17:04:36":14,"2023-06-27 17:04:37":16,"2023-06-27 17:04:38":13,"2023-06-27 17:04:39":8,"2023-06-27 17:04:40":12,"2023-06-27 17:04:41":22,"2023-06-27 17:04:42":3,"2023-06-27 17:04:43":5,"2023-06-27 17:04:44":7,"2023-06-27 17:04:45":12,"2023-06-27 17:04:46":1,"2023-06-27 17:04:47":6},"emails":{"2023-06-27 16:12:50":9986,"2023-06-27 16:28:25":6,"2023-06-27 16:29:19":4,"2023-06-27 16:29:20":14}}
```

I tried googling this with no help. Post updated with valid JSON.

Comment: Could you show a sample of the data in JSON format instead, so we can easily test it with the chartJS code? Presumably your php already outputs it as JSON? What you have shown us in your question is not JSON, even though that's how you described it

Comment: Apologies! Please see updated question.

Comment: Thanks. And have you then checked that after you've processed that data, your `Emails` and `Websites` variables contain data in the format chartJS says it expects in its documentation? Is there any difference there from what's documented and what you were expecting to see? Are there any console errors or anything like that?

Comment: I did an alert(Emails) and the data is just a list of numbers, console displays no errors.

Comment: I also tried replacing the Website and Emails with a fixed list and it still doesn't display.

Comment: Thanks. So... `data['emailss']` is a typo, which isn't helping. If you console.log(Emails) you get an empty list, unless you fix that

Comment: I tried to make a demo using your chartJS code and data: https://jsfiddle.net/pq4xnrkj/ . There are console errors about a date adapter...do you get the same errors in your console? If not, please show what you did in terms of setting up the date adapter

Comment: If we ditch the date formatting stuff on the scales and just go for a basic chart, we seem to get results: https://jsfiddle.net/pq4xnrkj/3/ (although the first data points on both the datasets dwarf the others to such an extent as to make the graph barely worth bothering with IMO).